# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 How to pass parameter from Main Suitelet to Custom Modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am a Javascript / PHP / Python developer for 25 years, and recently was hired as a NetSuite SuiteScript Javascript Developer.

NetSuite has very peculiar ways of doing things, so I must do things the NetSuite way.

Since NetSuite advises best practice of modular software architecture, this is what I am doing.

I have a main Suitelet script that is scaling to include one custom module with one function for each individual functionality.

I have created a custom Search, and I need to pass these results to various custom modules for further processing.

For example, I want to pass this "ListOfVendors" to a UI module that will contain this dynamic data in a MULTISELECT box.

I have tried to just pass this variable as an object, but in the module log it is showing up as not being passed,i.e. NULL.

The NetSuite ecosystem complicates things, so how do I pass this variable to another custom module?

Thanks.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.1
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 *@NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
 
 define(['N/log',
    './mod_search4vendors',
    './mod_ui'],

    function (log, mod_search4vendors, mod_ui) {

        // BEGIN ENTRY POINT FUNCTION #1
        function fn_EntryPointFunction1(context) {

            var ListOfVendors = mod_search4vendors.fn_Search4Vendors(context);

            var TEST_PASS_VARIABLES = mod_ui.fn_cr8_sublist(context);

        }
        // END ENTRY POINT FUNCTION #1

        return {
            onRequest: fn_EntryPointFunction1
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: Actually Netsuite modules follow the AMD module spec.  

You are not showing any of the code involved actually involved. i.e. where do you try to pass `ListOfVendors`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.1
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 *@NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
 
 define(['N/log',
    './mod_search4vendors',
    './mod_ui'],

    function (log, mod_search4vendors, mod_ui) {

        // BEGIN ENTRY POINT FUNCTION #1
        function fn_EntryPointFunction1(context) {

            var ListOfVendors = mod_search4vendors.fn_Search4Vendors(context);

            var TEST_PASS_VARIABLES = mod_ui.fn_cr8_sublist(context, ListOfVendors);

        }
        // END ENTRY POINT FUNCTION #1

        return {
            onRequest: fn_EntryPointFunction1
        };
    }
);
```